# Checking normalization condition of the neutron continuity equation

Tags: calculus, normed-spaces

So I've been given a reduced form of the neutron continuity equation that does not account for geometry:

$$\Sigma_s(E)\phi(E)=\int_0^\infty\Sigma_s(E^{'}→E)\phi(E^{'})dE^{'}+S(E),$$

for which the normalization condition is

$$\int_0^\infty f_s(E^{'}→E)dE=1.$$

Restricting focus to only elastic scattering, I get

$$f_s(E^{'}→E)dE=\begin{cases}\frac{dE}{(1-\alpha)E^{'}} & E\le E^{'}\le\frac{E}{\alpha}\\0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases},$$

where $\alpha$ is the scattering parameter:

$$\alpha=\left(\frac{A-1}{A+1}\right)^2,$$

where $A$ is the atomic mass of the nuclei.

How do I check this normalization condition? It's been awhile, I don't even know where to start.

Comment: How is $f_s$ related to $\Sigma_s, \phi, S$? I understand that $\phi$ is the density of neutrons and that $\Sigma_s$ is the collision kernel, but what is $f_s$?

Comment: Also shouldn't the integral be wrt $dE'$ in the normalisation equation and in the next one too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have to validate that 
$$
1 = \int_0^\infty f_s(E' \to E)dE = \int_{E \le E' \le E/\alpha} \frac{dE}{(1-\alpha)E'}
$$

To finish this, what is the relationship between $E$ and $E'$ and $\alpha$?

Comment: Ah I get it now. Just realized under those conditions $E^{'}=E-\frac{E}{\alpha}$. Thanks for the help!